# What are the covariates/explanatory variables in a news sentiment model?

Tags: fixed-effects-model, sentiment-analysis

In "Measuring News Sentiment", a working paper by the Fed, we have the following model:[image].

The index $a$ indexes the news articles. A fixed effect is a term (random or not) which is allowed to depend/be correlated with the observed explanatory variables.

However, what are the explanatory variables in the model in the picture?